# Conditional filter on 2 different columns of excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How shall I conditional filter in header1 and header3  columns so that the only row, I see in excel is Header1 having any No in-between x to another x of header3 column? If there is all No in header1 column for header 3's x to next x, then don't show up or unfiltered.

Excel macro or vba code would work too.
[image]
My solution- ​I do a filter on header1 column "yes" and manually copy it to header4.  Then filter on header3 column to x and Yes. Manually drag x until yes for the row to row.​

Results should like this

[image]

Comment solution- [image]

Comment: Can you get an example of what your result would have to look like? It's a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Edited the description to include the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't 100% understand your application but if you want a very quick and easy solution, you could add another column, with a formula in it and only use that column to filter.

So you would add a column called "Filter" and then have a formula in it something like:

`=IF(A2="YES","SHOW",IF(C2="X",IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW(C2)+1&":A"&ROW(C2)+IFERROR(MATCH("X",INDIRECT("C"&ROW(C2)+1&":C9000"),0)-1,10)),"YES")<1,"HIDE","SHOW"),E1))`

This works by:

1. Checking if the cells in column A contains "YES" and if so, adding "SHOW" to filter column
2. Checking if Column C contains "X" and if so;
3. Checking if any of the cells in column A before the next "X" appears in column C, contain "YES"

I used indirect references, so if you move columns around, you will need to adjust those.
I also assumed the max lines in your sheet to be 9000, if its more, you will need to adjust that part too.

If you copy and paste this formula into Cell $E$2 and then fill it down and then you should be able to filter to show only the "SHOW" cells and get what you are after.

**Screenshot of example**:

[image]

Comment: Can you upload this sheet?

Comment: I added the "Comment solution" portion to the description.

Comment: I notice on your uploaded example, the result is not displaying correctly, despite hitting the first IF statement criteria. Does cell A2 contain "Yes" with no spaces after? And is automatic calculation turned on?

Comment: @himmat if I have answered your question, would you mind upvoting my answer please as well as ticking it as "accepted". If I have not answered, let me know what you still need help with or if I have misunderstood and I will adjust my answer :)